# Writing a sorted csv file from a changing list of strings. Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a substantial amount of strings which consists of different values (like a phone number, name, etc) 
there is a total of 10 available values for each string, but every string may have only some of them, it might have 0, and it might have all of them.
I'm trying to find a way to open a csv file, containing 10 columns (as the possible values known to me already), and write every value of every string in his appropriate "cell", or leave a cell empty when needed.

for example:

```
str1=
name1
phonenum1
address1
email1

str2=
name2
phone2
email2


str3=
name3
adress3
email3
```

The resut I'm looking for in this example should be something like:

```
name  phonenum  adress  email
name1 phonenum1 adress1 email1
name2 phonenum2         email2
name3           adress3 email3
```

I've tried to split the strings into list, check every item in it for its appropriate column and write it in the specific cell it should go to, but I havn't found a way to write to a specific cell according to the 'type' of value (phone number, name, etc in this case).
I found some partial answers for rewriting an existing csv in a specific set cell (like all the cells in the 3rd column, or only the 3rd row in 4th column), nothing I could rearrenge to my goal successfully.

Two more difficulties I'm having are, 1. some of the values contain commas in them.
And 2. how to successfully recognize a missing value to keep his cell empty, in the example above- how can I recognize that the value I'm missing is the phone number and not the name or the adress for example?

Comment: For 1, csv format provides *quoting* to protect a delimiter inside a field. For 2, you know your input format, but I don't so I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

- Use Numpy's `genfromtxt()` method to properly read CSV files, it does all the seperation and comma handling for you
- Define a row class with primitive slots for the different values and blanks as default values
- Override the `__str__` method for your specific needs

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data looks like:

```
str1 = """
Adam
+48100200300
Street 2, Dublin
adam@adam.com
"""

str2 = """
Eva
48100000000
eva@eva.com
"""

str3 = """
Tom Jr
Street 1, London
tom@tom.com
"""

data = [str1, str2, str3]
```

Lets define fields that you are expecting:

```
field_names = [
    'name',
    'phone',
    'email',
    'address',
]
```

Because on example you did not have fields identified, and as I see may be different combinations,
then we need to recognize what field contains.

Lets write easy solution (definitely you will need more sophisticated recognize method - but this is an example)

```
import re

def recognize_field_name(line):
    if not line:
        return
    if re.fullmatch('\\+?[0-9]+', line):
        return 'phone'
    if '@' in line:
        return 'email'
    if ',' in line:
        return 'address'
    return 'name'
```

Then let's create input data:

```
results = []

for one_string in data:
    result = {}
    for l in one_string.split("\n"):
        value = l.strip()
        field_name = recognize_field_name(value)
        if field_name:
            result[field_name] = value
    results.append(result)
```

And finally we may store it:

```
import csv

with open("/tmp/out.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names)
    for r in results:
        writer.writerow(r)

with open("/tmp/out.csv") as show:
    print(show.read())
```

This will produce:

```
Adam,+48100200300,adam@adam.com,"Street 2, Dublin"
Eva,48100000000,eva@eva.com,
Tom Jr,,tom@tom.com,"Street 1, London"
```

*This solution is written in Python 3, but should be is easy to modify it for your (2.7) needs.*